# On PHP Error Apache gives 500 Error

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

Everytime I get an error in any of my PHP, my local Apache server gives me a 500 Internal Server error. I never seem to have problems with any of my CakePHP projects, but this is plain vanilla PHP and it is really slowing down progress having to guess at the error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Enable error reporting using the following PHP code:

```
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. So I could go into the php.ini file and set this also correct? So I don't have to have this code in my file all the time.

Comment: Why shouldn't you have it, put it under an 'if' statement that is turned on in development (or production in an  emergency, as you wouldn't want to shutdown the server for that). Check also my answer below.

Comment: please note that while this is good advice for a development server, on a live website you should switch error reporting off to avoid the end user seeing PHP error messages if they occur. You can still check the errors in the server error log.

Answer (score 2):

What @scompt wrote + you can always check the Apache error logs to know what happened. (hell, if you develop on linux, host on Linux, you **must** be familiar with the error logs).