# An error 500 occurred after edit PHP Configuration Editor

Tags: php, apache

An error 500 occurred after edit PHP Configuration Editor..

i changed allow_url_fopen from **ON** to **OFF**

Comment: and what happens if you change it back?

Comment: show us the code, probably a typo.

Comment: i think is over load in server ! .. i wait to 10 mint..

Comment: is this a QUESTION or a STATEMENT?

Comment: i ask is error for overload or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a function that requires `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled.  Since you have disabled it, this function is failing, and your error outputing is turned off.  Check your error log instead, and you will find the specific function giving you trouble.

Comment: i'll try.. Do you think that the server overload ?

Comment: No, I am sure that is not the case.  I am quite confident that if you just changed things and things broke, that your change is what broke it.  Try changing it back.

Comment: if this was the case then it would throw a php error rather than a 5 level error

Comment: @Ashwini, it depends on how error reporting is configured.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191755/on-php-error-apache-gives-500-error

Comment: @Brad, pardon my ignorance, that can actually be the case. The server doesn't support the request. I want to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Ashwini, we don't know what the actual error is yet... Anas hasn't posted it.  He needs to check his error log, but I'm sure if he just turns allow_url_fopen back on his trouble will go away.